# link /files to G:\files with apache

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

How can I link /files to G:\files with apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Alias /files/ "G:\files"
<Directory "G:\files" >
     Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews Includes
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This should do it.